# Read data in chunks using sockets

Tags: php, sockets

I want to send a request using persistant socket connection - to get huge text file from another server, through the API, in chunks.

I can see two layers of dividing the transfer here:
- Sending start and end pointers as parameters of the request, returning only this one part of text in the API, and using one fread to read the whole partial
- Returning the whole request from the API, and using many fread's to read it

What's the proper approach to do this?

Comment: I guess the question is just - what's the proper way to transfer big amount of data between APIs?